# Pointers inside functions

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

I need a clarification about pointers initialization.
I have tried to use a pointer to double without initializing it in the main of my code and it compiles/executes without any problem. Instead if I use a pointer without initialization inside a function, it makes the code crash at runtime.
I give you an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo()
{
    double *pt2 = new double;
    *pt2 = 10;

    cout << *pt2 << endl;
}

int main()
{
    double *pt;
    *pt = 5;

    foo();

    cout << *pt << endl;
}
```

In this code if I comment `double *pt2 = new double;`, it crashes, instead the pointer `pt` not initialized in the main does not create any issue.

Comment: if you comment this: ***double *pt2 = new double;*** the code is not even compiling..

Comment: `double *pt;*pt = 5;`: Assigning to a pointer with no allocated memory is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can cause anything.

Comment: In VS2017 it compile, but then it crashes. Anyway why this difference between pointers in the main and inside a function?

Comment: "... instead the pointer pt not initialized in the main does not create any issue." thats not correct, it is exactly the same issue with the other pointer: undefined behaviour. Thou shall not dereference an uninitialized pointer (even if initialized it has to point to something, not just somewhere). Just because it looks fine doesnt mean that it is fine

Comment: @ArnavBorborah assigning to the pointer would be `pt = 42;`, nothing wrong about that, the problem is dereferencing it

Comment: My bad, @user463035818 That's what I meant.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I know what you meant ;) its just that such details matter to avoid confusion. Pointers arent something magic, sloppy speaking they are just numbers, only when dereferencing them the problems start

Comment: @Mattia - For me VS2017 says *"warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'pt' used"*.

Comment: @Mattia 'why this difference', undefined behaviour means undefined behaviour, Because you use an uninitialized pointer your code has undefined behaviour. Crashing and running without any problem are both examples of undefined behaviour. Sorry to disppoint but there is no reason for the difference, it just undefined.

Comment: There is simply very little point in trying to figure out why *undefined behavior* behaves the way it does.

Comment: Just because something compiles and runs does *not* mean that it is correct and that it will always do the same thing. If your code has Undefined Behaviour *anything* can happen, all bets are off and a recompile with a different compiler (or same compiler on different platform) could give arbitrarily different results. Just re-running the same program could give different results.

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried to use a pointer to double without initializing it in the main of my code and it compiles/executes without any problem

Indirecting an uninitialized pointer has undefined behaviour. *"executes without any problem"* is something that can happen when behaviour of the program is undefined.

> Instead if I use a pointer without initialization inside a function, it makes the code crash at runtime.

Indirecting an uninitialized pointer has undefined behaviour. *"makes the code crash at runtime"* is something that can happen when behaviour of the program is undefined.

Anything can happen when behaviour is undefined.